# weblogic 10.3.4 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELContextListener

Tags: jsf, weblogic, el

I have a JSF 1.2 application which I intend to deploy to Weblogic 10.3.4. At local Tomcat environment it works fine. But when I try to deploy it to weblogic I am getting a `ClassNotFoundException` on `javax.el.ELContextListener`. When I add `el-api.jar` file, then I get a `LinkageError: loader constraint violation` on `javax.EL.ELResolver`. It is a deadly vicious circle.

At first I tried to deploy it as WAR. Then I created an enterprise project so that I can deploy as EAR, but it did not solve the problem. My EAR file structure is fine.

Firstly I got error below,

```
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELContextListener
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
```

When I add `el-api-2.2.jar` to `/WEB-INF/lib` of WAR or `/APP-INF/lib` of EAR, then I get loader constarint error;

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener failed: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.addELResolver(Ljavax/el/ELResolver;)V" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/GenericClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/faces/config/ConfigureListener, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/el/ELResolver used in the signature.
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.addELResolver(Ljavax/el/ELResolver;)V" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/GenericClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/faces/config/ConfigureListener, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/el/ELResolver used in the signature
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.registerELResolverAndListenerWithJsp(ConfigureListener.java:582)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:212)
```

What is the problem with it? I changed my classpath order but result was the same. My `web.xml` is declared as Servlet 2.5 and I have the following JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib`:

- commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.jar
- commons-digester-1.8.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- darkX-3.3.3.Final.jar
- glassX-3.3.3.Final.jar
- jsf-api.jar
- jsf-impl.jar
- jstl-1.2.jar
- laguna-3.3.3.Final.jar
- log4j-1.2.14.jar
- poi-3.7-20101029.jar
- quartz-all-1.8.4.jar
- richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar
- richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar
- richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final.jar
- scjd12.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.6.0.jar
- themes-3.3.3.Final.jar

Comment: What container are you using locally? What Servlet version is `web.xml` declared to? What JAR files do you have in `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: Hi Balusc I know you will answer:) thanks a lot firstly. I am using Apache Tomcat locally.  my web.xml version is 2.5   My Jar files inf WEB-INf/lib are;  commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
darkX-3.3.3.Final.jar
glassX-3.3.3.Final.jar
jsf-api.jar
jsf-impl.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
laguna-3.3.3.Final.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
poi-3.7-20101029.jar
quartz-all-1.8.4.jar
richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar
richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar
richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final.jar
scjd12.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.0.jar
themes-3.3.3.Final.jar

Comment: Here's a wild guess.  You (or one of the jars) is dependent on a newer version of EL than is in WebLogic 10.3.4.  They need ElContextListener, but WebLogic has none.  Was there more in the first stack trace?  If so, it _might_ show who heeds it.

Comment: @Mustafa: Weblogic already ships with JSF/JSTL bundled. It might have collided. Try removing them from your `/WEB-INF/lib` before exporting. I am not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure about the root cause and thus can't explain this problem. I don't use Weblogic and I haven't seen this before. Let me know if it works, then I'll repost it as an answer. @Ed Staub: The `ELContextListener` is part of Servlet 2.5 / JSP 2.1. Weblogic 10.3.4 is a Servlet 2.5 compatible container. So it must have it.

Comment: @BalusC thank you for your reply.  I did what you said but unfortunately it didn't work.  It throws 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:725)' After a bit googling I add <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class> to my web.xml  This time it throwed 'ClassNotFoundException:javax.el.ELContextListener'

Comment: `java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation` I think indicates duplicate versions of the class found from different classpaths. so the EL jars have to be remove I think from web-inf lib and app-inf lib

Comment: @JoseK  You are right I thought so when I saw that error. But when I remove that lib I get javax.el.ELContextListener  ClassNotFoundExcepiton

Comment: @Mustafa The `ELContextListener` should be in the system classpath. Have you configured a filtering classloader in your weblogic-application.xml (prefer-application-packages) or enabled prefer-web-inf-classes setting in weblogic.xml ? I usually see such issues when changing the classloader delegation model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I manage to find the solution.

**jsf-impl** jar includes "**ELContextListenerImpl**" class which implements "**ELContextListener**" interface.  And ELContextListener interface is included in the **wlfullclient-10.3.X.jar** in the server path.

If you dont have wlfullclient jar in the server path you will have "**ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELContextListener**" error.  Getting this error if you add el-api jar this time you will get "**LinkageError: loader constraint violation**" because versions of jars you used and the server has are different.  Anyway the problem will be resolved after creating wlfullclient-10.3.X.jar in the weblogic server.

In order to create that jar you can read this post: http://wls4mscratch.wordpress.com/2010/06/19/steps-to-build-a-wlfullclient-jar-in-wls-10-0-x-and-wls-10-3-x/

Answer (score 2):

You can try using filtering classloader.
weblogic-application.xml file can include something like:

```
  <prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.faces.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.apache.myfaces.*</package-name>
   </prefer-application-packages>
```

This enables WebLogic's filtering classloader to block your application from seeing the JSF in the container (the javax.faces and myfaces part in this case).  You need to keep everything that depends on your library also in your apps classloader, which is why I have facelets in this example.
Hope this helps..

Answer (score 2):

If you still get this error even though you did all the changes necessary related to el jars (i mean prefer-application-packages and other stuff in weblogic-application.xml etc.), I think there is something wrong in your web.xml file.
Please check that you have the lines below in your web.xml.

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Comment: Hi Baatar thank you for your reply.  Actually I give up migrating to upper version.  But I think your answer will be helpful.  I will consider your answer in the future.  Thank you very much.